# StateSpaceRealization "ControllableCompanion" does not generate ControllableCompanion form from DE

Tags: control-systems

Fixed in **10.1**

---

I must be doing something wrong, but do not see it. There is an option in Mathematica control system function `StateSpaceModel` where one asks it to generate the state space model in the [ControllableCompanion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceRealization.html) form. This should produce state space A,B,C,D where the B matrix (for one input) will have zeros except for one entry, as shown in the above link. Here is screen shot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when I try this on a proper transfer function, I do not get this form.

The problem only shows up when I enter the system as differential equation. If I enter the system directly as transfer function, then I do get the correct form.

Below, the I enter the differential equation, ask for SS, it is not controllable form. Yet, the transfer function is correct. If I take the transfer function generated, and ask for SS, now the state space show up in  controllable form.

```
tf=TransferFunctionModel[{{(4+2s+3 s^2+4 s^3)/(-7-2 s+6 s^2+s^3)}},s];
ss = StateSpaceModel[tf, StateSpaceRealization -> "ControllableCompanion"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is correct. Now trying from the differential equation itself, which has the above transfer function:

```
eq=y'''[t] +6 y''[t] -2 y'[t] -7 y[t]== 4 u'''[t] + 3 u''[t] + 2 u'[t] + 4 u[t];
ss = StateSpaceModel[{eq}, {{y'''[t], 0}, {y''[t], 0}, {y'[t], 0}, {y[t], 0}}, 
    {{u[t], 0}}, {y[t]}, t, StateSpaceRealization -> "ControllableCompanion"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets check to see if the above ODE has the same TF as before:

```
 Simplify@TransferFunctionModel[ss]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is the same. So when entering the system as DE, I do not get the controllable form. But same system entered as TF gives the the controllable form.

Any one sees what I am doing wrong? Mathematica 10.0.0 on windows 7

Comment: I havn't checked this, but at the first you have 3 outputs (32, 10, -21) while you have just one in the second (1, 0, 0). There might be the problem.

Comment: The `StateSpaceRealization` option was being ignored since v8 (and probably in CSP as well.) The fix should be in the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in **10.1** (looks like it was fixed since 10.0.2) Hence closing.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq = y'''[t] + 6 y''[t] - 2 y'[t] - 7 y[t] == 4 u'''[t] + 3 u''[t] + 
2 u'[t] + 4 u[t];
ss = StateSpaceModel[{eq}, {{y'''[t], 0}, {y''[t], 0}, {y'[t], 0}, 
   {y[t], 0}}, {{u[t], 0}}, {y[t]}, t, 
  StateSpaceRealization -> "ControllableCompanion"]
```